# No delete or move to trash in context menu in some directories (gnome)

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, gnome3, trash

On archlinux with gnome 3.16.1, in some directories, for example `/srv/http/website/public/img/` I don't have options to delete a file , or move to trash, in the rightclick context menu . I have to use `shift+del` to delete a file.

In others, like `/home/username/` I have these options.

It also seems, that I am the owner of the files in both cases and have `rwx` permissions. What else could be the reason?

Comment: That's right. And with the file manager thunar, I have `delete` and `move to trash` in the context menu. But both actions only lead to `delete`. I think that is because I don't seem to have a `trash` outside of the `/home/` partition. `Thunar` shows the options, but `nautilus` doesn't . Perhaps it is a nautilus or gnome issue.

Comment: Works fine here - same distro, same gnome version (no thunar though) - but I have no `/srv` dir, maybe nautilus is treating `srv` as a special backend... I don't know what to say...

Answer (score 3):

My situation may be similar.

I have two Ubuntu gnome systems, one desktop and one laptop.  Both have Apache installed in the default location of /var/www.  On both I set myself to owner, and sometimes www-data as group.

I was perplexed that, using Nautilus, I could not delete file on the desktop using the delete key, but I could on the laptop.  The desktop required right-clicking, and choosing delete. I later find out shift-delete would work, and neither method used the trash bin.

After much hair-pulling (well, not that much, as I don't have much), I realized the difference... my desktop has /var mounted in a separate partition.

It seems that Nautilus won't move a file to trash from a different partition, possibly only if you are not the owner of the root of that partition, so it can access the trash file on that partition.  I don't really want to be the owner of the /var partition, so I never tested this out.  Perhaps there is a way to mount the partition that would allow it.  There is some discussion about a similar problem on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/192629).

One problem with having a trashcan outside the user's directory that is r/w by normal users may be that other users may be able to see each other's files.

I hope at least to point out the possible reason, if not the solution.

Comment: For my own reference & others as well, here's a solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/560212/206719

Answer (score 1):

This could happen because you'd not have the permission to the "Trash" folder for that particular partition. Every partition has a hidden folder by the name `.trash-###` (where the hashes denote some number). Perhaps you don't have the permission for that folder. Try changing permissions of that folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm -rf /home/yourusername/.local/share/Trash && 
    mkdir /home/yourusername/.local/share/Trash
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux at Stack Exchange! In order to make your answer more useful... Can you explain why you think this would solve the reported problem? Also, use formatting markup, for instance indent lines with commands or contents of files by 4 spaces so they show up with monospace font and no wrapping other than the one you create (the `{}` button can do that for you.) See formatting help for more tips.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered somewhat similar problem in Gnome Files.

For all folder and files in my home dir, **Gnome Files** shows **Move to Trash** in context menu. But for files/folder in another device the context menu shows **Delete Permanently**. For example, if folder `/orange` is mounted on a separate partition/disk then for all files/folders under it the **Move to Trash** is not enabled.

This is because Files auto creates `Trash` dir under `$HOME/.local/share`. However as there is no `Trash` for `/orange` mount point the **Move to trash** is not enabled for /orange. To overcome this create `Trash` folder for each user in /orange. If uid of user foo is 1000 then create `/orange/.Trash-1000` and change its owner to foo.

```shell
sudo mkdir /orange/.Trash-1000
sudo chown foo:foo /orange/.Trash-1000
```

Now **Move to Trash** is enabled in context menu of all files/folders under `/orange`.